# Возможно ли перестановка строк в SQLite таблице?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Здравствуйте. Хотелось бы узнать, существует ли в SQLIte возможность  поменять местами несколько строк изменив их идентификатор, чтобы расставить таблицу в удобном мне порядке(без какой-либо явной последовательности). Пример того, что я хотел бы получить:

Было так:

```
1|Андрей
2|Игорь
3|Светлана
4|Константин
5|Федор
```

Стало так:

```
1|Андрей
2|Константин
3|Игорь
4|Светлана
5|Федор
```

(Вставить строку ближе к началу и изменить на одну позицию все последующие значения.)

Ну или так:

```
1|Андрей
2|Константин
3|Светлана
4|Игорь
5|Федор
```

(Поменять местами две строки.)

Если подобное возможно, хотелось бы увидеть пример, как это реализовать.

Comment: В принципе возможно. но вопрос для чего это нужно. И собственно все придется делать руками. Т.е. при перемещении записи самому понять в каком направлении, занят ли тот номер и сделать соотв. update всех номеров, т.е. освободить место, поменять у данной записи. Только лучше id для таких целей не использовать, а отдельное поле. id нужен для уникальной идентификации строки вне зависимости ни от чего (включая позицию где либо)

Comment: Смысл в том, что мне удобней, когда некоторые данные, скажем те, к которым я прибегаю чаше находятся в начале, поэтому решил отсортировать их в удобном порядке.  Хотя после вещего комментария, я действительно засомневался стоит ли с этим заморачиваться. Програмно конечно дело быстрей пойдет, но написание тоже время уйдет, в общем подумаю еще. В любом случае спасибо за Ваш ответ, теперь хотя бы знаю, что через командную строку, это не так просто реализовать.

Comment: Если вы хотите поднять данные к которым чаще обращаются то тогда надо завести поле "количество обращений" и увеличивать его на 1 при каждом обращении. А при выводе делать order by это_поле desc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм выполнения данной задачи может быть таким:

```
/* Создаём таблицу для хранения переменных */
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS variables (name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT);

/* Инициируем переменные id_1 и id_2. Они содержат ID тех записей, какие мы хотим
   поменять местами */
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO variables VALUES ('id_1', 1); 
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO variables VALUES ('id_2', 3);

/* Так как изменений будет больше, чем одно, выполним их 
   в транзакции begin; ...; commit; */
begin;

/* Сохраняем имя записи с ID, который указан в id_1, во временную переменную */
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO variables VALUES 
( 'tmp_name', (SELECT NAME FROM grand_table WHERE id = (SELECT value FROM variables WHERE name = 'id_1') ) );

/* Назначаем этой же записи, значение из записи с id_2 */
UPDATE grand_table SET name = (
    SELECT name FROM grand_table WHERE id = (SELECT value FROM variables WHERE name = 'id_2') 
) WHERE id = (SELECT value FROM variables WHERE name = 'id_1');

/* И наконец, записи id_2 назначаем значение из временной переменной */
UPDATE grand_table SET name = (SELECT value FROM variables WHERE name = 'tmp_name' ) 
WHERE id = (SELECT value FROM variables WHERE name = 'id_2');

commit;
```